# limit points of asymptotically regular orbits are fixed points

Tags: limits, dynamical-systems

In a paper the following theorem is stated:

> Let $T:X\longrightarrow X$ be a continuous map and $(X,d)$ a metric space. If $d(T^{n}x,T^{n+1}x)\longrightarrow 0$ (i.e. the orbit starting at $x$ is asymptotically regular), then any limit point $p$ of the orbit $\{T^nx\}$ is a fixed point of $T$.

I deem the statement wrong. Here is the proof provided:

> If $T^{n_k}x\longrightarrow p\in X$ then $p=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}T^{n_k+1}x=T(\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}T^{n_k}x)=Tp$.

To the best of my knowledge, assuming $p\in X$ is a mistake here, as a limit point of the orbit need not belong to $X$ (it is not assumed compact, so it may belong to its boundary), and as a result the second equality of the last line may not hold. Am I missing something?

Comment: A limit point always belongs to the space under consideration. Where else should it live?

Comment: If $X\subset Y$, and $X$ is not compact, it could be in the $Cl_Y(X)\setminus X$.

Comment: But then you have added something that is not part of the theorem. There is no $Y$ in the theorem and no reason why there should be. $(X,d)$ is the metric space and thus the whole universe for the context of the theorem. // And the condition would have to be "closed", not "compact", as the properties under consideration do not lead to Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Yes, closed would be even more general than compact, I mentioned compact as it is a common hypothesis mentioned in many contexts, but since a subset of a metric space is a metric space, with the same metric, wouldn t you agree that the statement requires an additional hypothesis (whether closed or compact). All I am saying is that in full generality, as it is stated (and also the context of the paper is very general as well) further properties of X must be added to this statement.

Comment: $X$ as its own space is already closed. Any sequence that converges in $X$ has its limit in $X$. There can be no convergence without limit element. Nearly-convergence without limit is the Cauchy condition, but as said, that does not play a role here. The theorem is only about those limit points that exist, and are thus elements of $X$.

Comment: So you are saying that the author, by saying ‘any limit point $p$’ actually means ‘any limit point $p\in X$’ essentially.

Comment: Yes, that is the common definition of a limit of a sequence. The limit is a property of a pair of a sequence and a point, not a construction of new objects possibly outside $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the existence of a limit point ($p$) is a hypothesis of the theorem.  It is overloaded in the “any”.  Restating the theorem can (perhaps) make things clearer:

> Let $T:X\longrightarrow X$ be a continuous map and $(X,d)$ a metric space.  Suppose that $d(T^{n}x,T^{n+1}x)\longrightarrow 0$ (i.e. the orbit starting at $x$ is asymptotically regular).  Further suppose that the orbit $\{T^nx\}$ has a limit point $p$.  Then $p$ is a fixed point of $T$.

Answer (score 1):

The common definition of the limit of a sequence is a point of the space that the sequence approaches arbitrarily close, having only finitely many points above any given distance. The central point here is that the limit point is a point of the given topological state from the start.

There is the closely related property of a Cauchy sequence that only demands, in a metric space, that the diameter of the sequence remainder reduces to zero if one removes more and more elements from the start of the sequence. This property has no concrete limit point as a precondition, so it can be used to characterize sequences that maybe should be convergent, but are not. This leads to ideas like the closure of a space in some embedding space, the completion, or adding points at infinity where sequences can diverge to.

But while the cited series property superficially looks like the Cauchy property, it is not, it only serves to show that shifted sub-sequences necessarily have the same limit point. At no point in theorem or proof is there a hint of some surrounding space or the addition of external limit point candidates. The theorem makes only claims for the situation that there happens a limit point to be present, it remains trivially true if there actually are no limit points of any sub-sequence.